# Ambassador routing WebSockets in Kubernetes

Tags: websocket, kubernetes, api-gateway

I'm trying to expose some services using WebSockets on DigitalOcean Kubernetes using Ambassador and DO LoadBalancer.

When exposing WebSocket service directly using LoadBalancer it works (I can connect to it).

But when Trying o route it trough Ambassador it doesn't. At this point I don't know if I missconfigured something or there is an bug in Ambassador.

When testing with Ambassdor samples for HTTP routing it worked, but there is zero documentation about using WebSockets.

Here is configuration for all relevelant pieces:

Ambassador RBAC:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    service: ambassador-admin
  name: ambassador-admin
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: ambassador-admin
    port: 8877
    targetPort: 8877
  selector:
    service: ambassador
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: ambassador
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
 - services
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
 - configmaps
  verbs: ["create", "update", "patch", "get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
 - secrets
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: ambassador
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ambassador
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ambassador
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ambassador
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ambassador
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
      labels:
        service: ambassador
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ambassador
      containers:
      - name: ambassador
        image: quay.io/datawire/ambassador:0.40.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 400Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 100Mi
        env:
        - name: AMBASSADOR_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
        - name: admin
          containerPort: 8877
        - name: websocket1
          containerPort: 8010
        - name: websocket2
          containerPort: 8011
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /ambassador/v0/check_alive
            port: 8877
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 3
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /ambassador/v0/check_ready
            port: 8877
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 3
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Ambassador service:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ambassador
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
   - port: 80
     name: http
   - port: 8010
     name: websocket1
   - port: 8011
     name: websocket2
  selector:
    service: ambassador
```

Websocket Pod:

```
---
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Pod
 metadata:
   name: web-socket-test
   labels:
     app: web-socket-test
 spec:
   containers:
     - name: web-socket-test
       image: ksdn117/web-socket-test
       ports:
         - containerPort: 8010
         - containerPort: 31448
         - containerPort: 8011
         - containerPort: 31057
```

websocket service:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-socket-test
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
     ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v0
      kind:  Mapping
      name:  web-socket-test_mapping
      prefix: /web-socket-test/
      service: web-socket-test
      use_websocket: True
spec:
  selector:
    app: web-socket-test
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8011
    targetPort: 31057
    name: websocket1
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 31057
    targetPort: 8010
    name: websocket2
```

Comment: were you able to fix it ?

Comment: I didn't. I ended up creating my own simple gateway for Websocket based messages, as they had very rigid structure and in the end I didn't needed generic solution for it.

Comment: I have this weird problem, that websocket connections dont establish conenction to upstream server with ambassador v 0.74

Comment: UPDATE: If this helps anyone, Upgrading to the latest ambassador fixes my problem of websocket not getting routed. We moved to Ambassador `1.4.2`.